# Trouble making a GET request with the requests library in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, xcode, response

I'm currently working on a Python project where I need to make a GET request to a remote API using the `requests` library. Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.example.com/data"
response = requests.get(url)

print(response.text)
```

I expected to see the data from the API in the console, but I'm encountering an issue. Instead of the data, I'm getting an error message: [Insert the specific error message here]. I've checked the API documentation, and I believe I'm using the requests library correctly.

I've also tried a few things, like checking my internet connection, ensuring the API endpoint is correct, and checking for typos in my code, but I'm still stuck. Can someone please help me identify what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?

Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: Your use of requests.get() is correct but there is no such host which will result in a requests.exceptions.ConnectionError exception